# Internet data card connection MTNL 3G in Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: internet

I wish to connect internet data card from MTNL 3G 'jadoo' with Ubuntu 12.10. How can I do it? I see a deb package but I am unable to use apt as the OS is not updated or apt has not been installed. Is there any other way round.

Answer (score 1):

Normally to install a .deb package, you just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, navigate to the folder where the file was downloaded, and run the command(s) below:

```
sudo dpkg -i <package_name>
```

Now keep in mind that a deb package may not have all the needed dependencies.  You can try to see if it works.